# Paypal button doesn't load approx 50% of the time. Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, paypal, rxjs

I have a page with a paypal button, and it doesn't load half the time. I just refreshed the page 30 times in a row. It alternated working 9 times in a row, then it didn't load for 11 straight times, then it loaded for 10 straight times. I am completely lost. Same thing happens in test as it does live.

The error when the button doesn't load

```
deposittest.component.ts:224  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
    at deposittest.component.ts:218:36
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:26321:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at zone.js:1257:36
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:25998:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25998:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
```

ts file with some code removed

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { loadScript, PayPalNamespace } from "@paypal/paypal-js";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-deposittest',
  templateUrl: './deposittest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deposittest.component.css']
})
export class DeposittestComponent implements OnInit {
  depositState$: Observable<State<CustomHttpResponse<User>>>;
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<CustomHttpResponse<User>>(null);
  private isLoadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isLoading$ = this.isLoadingSubject.asObservable();
 
  DataState = DataState;

  private isLoggedInSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isLoggedIn$ = this.isLoggedInSubject.asObservable();

  PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID: string = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  myAmount: any

  @ViewChild('paypalRef', { static: false }) private paypalRef!: ElementRef;

  constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService, private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.depositState$ = this.userService.depositInit$()
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.dataSubject.next(response);
          return {
            dataState: DataState.LOADED, appData: response
          };
        }),
        startWith({ dataState: DataState.LOADING }),
        catchError((error: string) => {
          return of({ dataState: DataState.ERROR, error })
        })
      )
    this.renderPaypalButton();
  }

  renderPaypalButton() {
    let orderRef: string | null = null;
    loadScript({
      "clientId": this.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
      currency: 'USD',
      disableFunding: 'paylater,credit,card,venmo',
    })
      .then((loadedPaypal) => {
        if (loadedPaypal) {
          const paypal: PayPalNamespace = loadedPaypal;
          paypal.Buttons({
            style: {
              layout: 'vertical',
              color: 'blue',
              shape: 'rect',
              label: 'paypal',
            },
            createOrder: (data, actions) => {
              const postData = {
                amount: this.myAmount,
                state: this.state
              };
              return fetch(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/user/create_paypal_transaction', {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(Key.TOKEN),
                  'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(postData)
              })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((response) => {
                  //  console.log("create order response ");
                  //  console.log(response);
                  //  console.log("create order id ");
                  //  console.log(response.data.order.id);
                  return response.data.order.id;
                });
            },
            onApprove: (data, actions) => {
              return fetch(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + `/user/paypal/capture_order/${data.orderID}`, {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(Key.TOKEN),
                  'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
              })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((response) => {
                  this.paypalRedirect(response.data.order.status, orderRef);
                });
            },
            onCancel: () => {
              // 
            },
            onError: (err) => {
              this.notificationService.onError('Error processing deposit.');
              this.paypalRedirect('ERROR', orderRef);
            }
          }).render(this.paypalRef.nativeElement);
        } else {
          console.error("");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("", error);
      });
  }
  paypalRedirect(status: string, orderRef: string | null) {
    switch (status) {
      case 'COMPLETED':
        if (orderRef) {
         this.notificationService.onDefault('Payment Successful.');
          this.router.navigate(['/paypal/result/success/']);
        } else {
          console.error("Missing success redirect");
        }
        break;
      case 'ERROR':
        if (orderRef) {
          this.notificationService.onError('Payment could not be completed.');
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        } else {
          console.error("Missing failure redircte");
        }
        break;
      default:
        console.error("redirection.");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

html file

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(depositState$ | async) as state" [ngSwitch]="state.dataState">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="DataState.LOADED">
        <app-navbar [user]="state?.appData?.data?.user"></app-navbar>
        <section>
            <div id="payment" class="mt-3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div style="font-weight: bold;">Name on file: {{ state?.appData?.data?.user.firstName+'
                            '+state?.appData?.data?.user.lastName}} </div>
                        <div class="mt-2" style="font-style: italic;font-size: 1rem;">Your name on file must match the
                            name associated with your form of payment.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="input" class="form-group mt-3">
                    <label style="font-size: .8rem;" class="me-2">Enter Amount: $10 - $999</label>
                    <input type="text" (keypress)="decimalFilter($event)" placeholder="Enter amount here" ngModel
                        name="myAmount" (ngModelChange)="myAmount=$event" value="{{myAmount }}"
                        class="form-control mb-2">
                </div>
                <div #paypalRef></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="DataState.LOADING">
        <div>Loading...</div>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="DataState.ERROR">
        <div>{{ state.error }}</div>
    </ng-container>
    <app-authfooter></app-authfooter>
</ng-container>
```

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you

Comment: You have a race condition. `renderPaypalButton ` is an asynchronous operation tht should return a promise so it can be managed appropriately. Instead you're calling it from the subscribe callback of another asynchronous operation in a fire and forget manner. Not 100% sure if this is what's causing your problem but it's definitely bad code.

Comment: A bit of a "code wall" challenge here, try to reduce to a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Also, I think you shouldn't be attempting to render the button in `ngOnInit` because the children might not be ready. Try placing it in `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: Thank you very much Aluan, moving the renderPaypalButton into ngAfterViewInit has it working better. For some reason the button now only doesn't load if you leave the page, then come back to it. It works on a page reload though.

Comment: How can ngAfterViewInit be executing before some function inside of ngOnInIt? This is happening to me.

Comment: @TM You can attach the render code to navigation end router event, because back button generally causes issues in angular applications!

Comment: @TM I'm glad that helped but you need to look at the first comment. You still have a race condition because you're using fire and forget asynchronous operations instead of composing them. At the very least, if you have a function that starts a promise, you should return that promise so that the calling method can decide how to handle it. `renderPaypalButton` should return the promise it creates. If it did so, you could compose it with the observable from the deposit service using pipe and merge map. Fundamentally fire and forget should be the exception not the rule for Observables and Promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition going on, where you wait for `depositState$` to load and render the page. Simultaneously the `renderPaypalButton()` method gets called. If loading the state is fast enough the paypal-buttons will render just fine. If not the template is not available at the time you try to render the buttons.

So what you should do is introduce a `tap` function where you check if the state is defined and therefor your template is ready and place `renderPaypalButton()` in there.

```
this.userService.depositInit$()
    .pipe(
      // ...other code
      tap((pageLoaded) => {
       if (pageLoaded) this.renderPaypalButtons()
      })
    )
```

This is also why placing `renderPaypalButtons()` in ngAfterViewInit won`t make any difference since your whole page depends on the first *ngIf.

Comment: Thank you! I had figured out removing the ngIf was allowing the renderButton function to work, but I hadn't figured out how to have both working.